# Vim: source code formatting

Tags: c++, formatting, vim

Take a look at the enum:

```
enum TestEnum
{
    First = 1,
    Second = 2,
    Unknown = 3,
    TestTestTest = 100,
    Zero = 0,
    Foo = 123,
}
```

How can I use the whole power of Vim to reformat it?

```
enum TestEnum
{
    First           = 1,
    Second          = 2,
    Unknown         = 3,
    TestTestTest    = 100,
    Zero            = 0,
    Foo             = 123,
}
```

Personally, I'm moving line by line and tabbing. It is the same as I would do that in any regular editor. How to do that the right way?

The same for class members:

```
class Foo
{
    SuperFoo foo1;
    RegularFoo foo2;
    SuperiorFoo foo3;
    YetAnotherFoo foo4;
    Bar bar;
}
```

to something like

```
class Foo
{
    SuperFoo        foo1;
    RegularFoo      foo2;
    SuperiorFoo     foo3;
    YetAnotherFoo   foo4;
    Bar             bar;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: +1. Intersting question. However, it seems rather specific. It probably can be done using a script but I highly doubt that there is a native command for such things.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It would be nice to use native dot-magic there or something like that.

Comment: There's a reason there are plugins that do this - there's no native command, at least nothing nearly so simple as `:Align =`.

Comment: While this formatting might be nice, it's horrible when you need to create diffs and add a new, long, option. You'll have to update many lines in this case which creates a rather ugly diff.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can harvest from two plug-ins that can do this stuff:

- [Align.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294)
  , or
- [Tabular.vim](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular)

Answer (score 3):

The Align.vim plugin is probably the way to go, but if you wish to have it handy on a standard installation, you could always filter through awk to get some generic functionality with not *too* much work.

For TestEnum you would do something like

```
'<,'>!awk '{printf "^I\%-20s\%-20s\%-20s\n", $1, $2, $3}'
```

after visually selecting the braced contents (viB is awesome here.)

For Foo you would do

```
'<,'>!awk '{printf "^I\%-20s\%-20s\n", $1, $2}'
```

You could probably make it variable width with an awk for-loop but at the cost of the easy and fast to type version here.

If you have the unix utility `col` handy, you might simply try

```
'<,'>!col -x
```

But here your mileage will really vary, as this is not the intended use of the utility.

Comment: And you don't have to undo and repeat a lot to get the column widths in awk right; you can just use visual block mode (ctrl-v) to lop off a bit, assuming you overestimated.

Answer (score 0):

Align or Tabular sound like the way to go, but I will also mention the Unix utility `column`, which is pretty nifty and more people should know about.
Unix-specific, obviously. (On openSuSE 12.3, it's in the util-linux package; likely different on other distributions.)
To invoke it within vim, visually select the lines you want to align, then
`:!column -t`
So with the visual range that vim fills in for you when you hit `:` with lines selected, you get:
 `:'<,'>!column -t`
(By default it separates on whitespace, but you can change that with the `-s <separator>` option.)
It aligns things such that each column is just long enough for its longest member.